# How to get private key from paramiko in string?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

How to get private key in string from below...

```
key = paramiko.RSAKey.generate(1024)
ssh_key = 'ssh-rsa' + key.get_base64()
```

**Updated:** I wanted to get Private Key from the ssh_key variable, any idea how to get it?

Like,

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nLevEvuunmIk+ukyuoieKmqBOGpqJBk1uBZg0Owhqxq4ezq6ZI6Fy\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's alright i upvoted it to neutralize the down vote :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `write_private_key()` method of the `key` object:

```
import StringIO
out = StringIO.StringIO()
key.write_private_key(out)
print out.getvalue()
```

Comment: For Python 3, one has to use `io.StringIO()` instead of `StringIO.StringIO()`.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to reset the StringIO (using Python 3)

```
from io import StringIO
out = StringIO()
key.write_private_key(out)
out.seek(0)
key_str = out.read()
```